# Facebook app submit action type

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading about this on StackOverflow and facebook doc, yet I dont seem to be able to submit my action type.

I have the following code from the FB doc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("Function begins");
    function postForm()
      {
console.log(FB);
FB.api(
    '/me/concoursvelirium:form',
    'post',
    { recipe: 'http://concours.gestev.com/fbvel2012/form.php' },
    function(response) {
    console.log("Stay");
       if (!response || response.error) {
          console.log("error:  " + response);
       } else {
          console.log('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
       }
    });
   }
</script>
```

I have added my values from FB autogenerated values, it now looks like this:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# concoursvelirium: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/concoursvelirium#">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="194081877384051" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="concoursvelirium:form" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Concours Vélirium" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.velirium.com/++resource++snowjamboree.theme.images/velirium-avatar-128x128.png" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Concours Vidéotron au Vélirium" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://concours.gestev.com/fbvel2012/form.php" />
```

And yet I see no output in the console past the `console.log(FB);`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm also getting the `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` error, but I have read here that I should just ignore it.

Ty, Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue, and it's not that hard, provided you don't read too much facebook's doc. Even tough they give you a `POST` command and a JS code to validate your action, I wasn't able to validate mine. Tough there's an easier way to submit actions for approval:

- Head to your app settings In the open graph section go to dashboard
- Next to the action type you want to submit click the "get code"
  link(remember.. action type, not the object type "get code" button)
- Copy the code inside the "Create a new Complete action:" box in a
  linux terminal If you got an output like: {"id":"[YOUR-ID-NUMBER]"}
  congratulations, you can now submit your action!

GL HF everyone

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems here:

1. `og:url` should have a valid url.
2. `og:image` can't refer to an image hosted on Facebook's servers.

Comment: Oh, that's straight from FB autogenerated values. My bad, I'll add what I ACTUALLY have from my webpage. I meant to show where I got my values from

Comment: @Axel : you can use this tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
 to know exact problems in your app.

Comment: @Eswar Rajesh Pinapala: I was aware of the tool, the best I can come up with is:

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Tiny og:image All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.

Unless I'm not supposed to debug my og:url?

Comment: I click the button on your page and your script fires. I get an error `[object Object]` on line 39. I was never presented a dialog to login to your app. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: I saw the error `[object Object]` once, I would love it if you could tell me where you saw it. Was it on http://concours.gestev.com/fbvel2012/form.php ?

Comment: Yes, after clicking the "Participer" button at the bottom of the page. I did not enter any values into the form.

Comment: I think my chrome debug console may be making the error dissapear after a fraction of a second. I'll try to add a login interface and try to catch that pesky error tomorrow morning.